Set up Postfix to send mail through Google's smtp-relay?
I'm trying to set up a postfix-server to relay emails through using Google's smtp-relay from, using another domain-name than the one's registered with Google. I have had this working for years using an old config of hMailServer that I've set up like 10 years ago, so I have completely forgot how I solved it back then. But since I'm planning to get rid of the Windows server I ran at home completely, I would like to move my mail-relay over to one of my linuxservers instead, so I started looking into setting this up with postfix.
My first attempt was setting it up using the smarthost-option, and it seemed pretty straight forward. I emails to send as expected but this was pretty equal to not having a relay-server at all in the sense that I was unable to sign the emails sent from my other domain using my DKIM-key, and my Google workspace domain was still the "sender" responsible for the emails if looking at the header (or if using gmail, it even says "on behalf of: otherdomain.tld" next to the sender-address). So this lead me to fire up a Windows-vm and copying over my old hMailServer that I havent touched for a decade and look into what I may have missed, and I realized that rather than using Googles smtp-relay directly as the sender, I connected to my hMailServer that forwarded everything to Google, which finally sent the mail to the reciever. And sending mails this way worked as intended by having otherdomain.tld as the "sender" and sign all emails sent from this domain using my DKIM-signature set up on the server. So, next step was to try to configure Postfix in a similar way, so I just purged everything and started over, this time using the "Internet site" option. After reading some docs about how to set this up, I finally ended up with a config looking like this:
main.cf:
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname =  otherdomain.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname  # This file contains: otherdomain.tld
mydestination = $myhostname, otherdomain.tld, address.of.server.tld, localhost
relayhost = [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd

smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

And yes, the sasl-password is generated and mapped correctly using my "app password" from Google Workspaces, I used the same method the first time I've set this up using the smarthost-option so I know there is no problems with this part.
On otherdomain.tld I've set up this TXT-record:
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
and I haven't created a DKIM-keypair of the server yet because I want to make sure everything works before stepping further, so for now I have no DNS-entrys for that, and dmarc is set up as p=quarantine;
When I try to send a test-mail this time, I only get:
[Timestamp] address.of.server.tld postfix/smtp[355743]: connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[108.177.96.28]:587: Connection timed out
[Timestamp] address.of.server.tld postfix/smtp[355743]: DCF996380B: to=<sometestexample@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=52, delays=22/0.04/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[108.177.96.28]:587: Connection timed out

and I can't figure out why this is not working. I know that I can't directly compare hMailServer configs to postfix, but it looks like I have taken all steps neccessary(?). I even tried to change from port 25 to 25025 in master.cf just in case my hostingprovider was blocking requests on port 25, and since I have ran this solution from home before (which obviously blocks port 25) I know that this really doesn't matter for the sending to Googles relay, but this made no difference either. So I'm currently stuck with "Connection timed out" to Googles smtp-server and I have no idea why; the IP of the server is added as a trusted device on Google adminpage, the authorization works because I have succeeded using the same approach with the smarthost-option, I have port 25/25025 open in my firewall, and I have added Google to my spf-record. I'm out of ideas, would really appreciate any help with this.
Also - I havent found a way to set up users/passwords so that I can auth myself outside of the server itself, to be able to send mails from other machines. E.g instead of authing with my Workspaceaddress:password I want to auth as user@otherdomain.tld:password for sending email from another machine through my postfix-server (that will relay everything through Googles smtp-relay). Thanks on beforehand!
